# can not read file from linux system using java

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.04, file-handling

I am trying to read/write files on Ubuntu 12.04.
I set permission of that directory by chmod -R 777 .
But still when I call canRead() method on that directory it returns false.

my directory is /root/Temp

please help me to solve this problem

Code (*copied from comments*):

```
File xyz = new File("/root/Temp"); 
System.out.println("filename :"+xyz.getPath()); 
System.out.println("can read :"+xyz.canRead()); 
String[] children = xyz.list();
```

Children is `null`, output of can read is `false`.

Comment: For better help sooner, post your code as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem. This allows users to copy/paste and reproduce your issue. Include in your example the shell commands you used to create the directory.

Comment: run your program with sudo Eg. sudo java HelloWorld.

Comment: I've voted to re-open as we now have the code. Although it would be beneficial if you can still post the shell commands that construct your directory.

Comment: before specifying path give sudo..and try to pipe your password to the sudo command..

Comment: I fired command with sudo but still its not giving permissions to read/write files using java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running your program as root? it is not sufficient changing the permissions of **/root/temp**, if you are not the user **root** you wont be able to "go through" the dir **/root** unless you also change the permissions of the dir **/root** .

Comment: I am root user. and creating folder using sudo.

Comment: Can you post your code as suggested by @DuncanJones ? that way we could help you better

Comment: `code` File xyz = new File("/root/Temp");
System.out.println("filename  :"+xyz.getPath());
System.out.println("can read  :"+xyz.canRead());
        String[] children = xyz.list(); `code` children is null, output of can read is false.

Comment: @LaxmikantKumbhare What do you expect to read? Make sure `Temp` folder is not empty...

Comment: Works for me, using the code you posted as comment and running it as root. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Temp directory has 6 directories. I want to count number of directories under this Temp directory. And want to create new directory. if I already have 6 directories then I want to create new one with name workspace_7

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same while doing XML Parsing using Java SAX Parser. My file is not read by the java program. The mistake I done was, I didn't specify the file name correctly. 
After your ***/root/Temp*** you have to add some more details too.
For example : ***/root/Temp/example.xml*** 
Then your program will work fine.
Hope this helps!!